# d3.js Time Scale Axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a scatter plot created using d3.js that I am trying to add an x axis to which will range from 12AM to 12AM i.e. spanning 24 hours. The nature of the graph is that the data will change depending on user input however I keep receiving the same error for however I try to append the axis.

I receive the error:
**d3.v4.min.js:2 Error:  attribute transform: Expected number,
"translate(NaN,0)".**

Here is my code in which I have tried to include only that which is important for my query. (timeLog is my array of data)

```
var parseTime = d3.utcParse("%H:%M");
var midnight = parseTime("00:00");
var height = $("#scatter").height();
var width = $("#scatter").width();

var max = Math.max(timeLog);
var min = Math.min(timeLog);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
 .domain([0,d3.max(timeLog)])
 .range([0,height]);

var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
 .domain(d3.range(0,timeLog.length))
 .range([0,width]);

d3.select("#scatter").append('svg')
    .attr('width',width)
    .attr('height',height)
    .style('background', '#f4f4f4')
    .selectAll('circle')
        .data(timeLog)
        .enter().append('circle')
        .style('fill', 'black')
        .style('stroke','none')
        .attr('cx',function(d, i){
            return xScale(i);
            })
        .attr('cy',function(d){
            return height - yScale(d);
        })
        .attr('r',2);

var hScale = d3.scaleUtc()
 .domain([midnight,d3.time.day.offset(midnight,1)])
 .range([0,width]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
 .scale(hScale)
 .tickFormat(d3.time.format.utc("%I %p"))

var xGuide = d3.select('svg')
 .append('g')
  .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    xAxis(xGuide)
    xGuide.attr('transform','translate(0,' + height + ')')
    xGuide.selectAll('path')
        .style('fill','black')
        .style('stroke','black')
    xGuide.selectAll('line')
        .style('stroke','black')
```

I am fairly new to d3.js and am attempting to teach myself the basics so any feedback that would help me identify the cause of the error would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**
I have made some changes after discovering some of my syntax was outdated and updated the above code, I am now not receiving any error messages however the axis is still not displaying. Is there perhaps some attribute I am missing?
Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: The code you posted is using d3 v3 syntax which is slightly different from the syntax for v4 `d3.scale.ordinal` is now `d3.scaleOrdinal` and `d3.time.format` is now `d3.timeFormat`. [Here is a complete list of the changes.](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md)

Comment: Also ` var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(d3.range(0,timeLog.length)).rangeBands([0,width]);` the domain should be `.domain(timeLog MIN, timeLog MAX)`

Comment: Thanks @pmkro ! that helped,  the error messages have gone but the axis is still not appearing, I have updated the code in the question. Do you spot anything obvious i'm missing?Apologies if ive made a trivial mistake, i'm still getting to grips with the basics of d3.

Comment: `xAxis(xGuide)` should be the other way around --> `xGuilde.call(xAxis)` and your yScale is still showing `d3.scale.linear` instead of `d3.scaleLinear`